# Can't give bounty for a question when having enough rep points and after deleting my own answer

Tags: bug, bounty

I can't give bounty for [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178067/sshguard-does-one-to-change-any-configuration-for-basic-usage-of-the-program) question when having enough rep points and after deleting my own answer to it...

I tried to fully refresh the browser after deleting the answer (CTRL+F5), after much time also, but still can't give bounty. I'm just being told the question is eligible to bounty since time XYZ and this link doesn't allow to start offering a bounty:

---

[image]

---

Any ideas what to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

From [StackOverflow help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

> To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).

You don't have the reputation needed for 100 yet